# Error when Executing GraphQL query in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, graphql

I've quite a bit of exerience with Neo4J but a noob with graphql

I created my graphql schema by running:

```
CALL graphql.idl(null)
```

I have a node type with three labels. I tried to run the following query in graphiql and got the same error. Due to the stack, I wondered if graphiql was adding meta and moved to the neo4j browser - same error.

The query:

```
CALL graphql.execute('mutation { createArrival(uuid:"graphql")}')
```

The error:

```
    Failed to invoke procedure `graphql.execute`: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error executing GraphQL Query:
 ExceptionWhileDataFetching{path=[createArrival]exception=org.neo4j.graphdb.QueryExecutionException: Invalid input 'n': expected whitespace, comment, '{', node labels, MapLiteral, a parameter, a relationship pattern, '(', '.', '=' or "+=" (line 1, column 69 (offset: 68))
"CREATE (node:Arrival) SET node = {properties} SET node:`Event`, SET node:`Configuration`"
                                                                     ^locations=[SourceLocation{line=1, column=12}]}
```

I'm probably doing something really obviously wrong but any help would be appreciated

Comment: Sorry that's a bug which will be fixed in the next release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed as a bug by @michael-hunger